# How to save Room database to different storage path

Tags: android, android-room

I want to save  room databases on different location.

i.e. The default save path of the database is in internal storage,
I want to create an android application that save the db on different path (ex. External storage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
        AppDatabase.class, "dbNameWithPath").build();
```